# SELECT in 2 merged 3-Tables relation with IN() clause and a COUNT for each relation

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

In a 3-Tables relation Query, I have this following two Queries for each relation:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bcc34/3/0

```
SELECT d.`id`, COUNT(da.`doc_id`)
FROM `docs` d

LEFT JOIN `docs_scod_a` da ON da.`doc_id` = d.`id`
LEFT JOIN `scod_a` a ON a.id = da.`scod_a_id`

WHERE a.`ver_a` IN ('AA', 'AB')

GROUP BY d.`id`;

| id | COUNT(da.`doc_id`) |
|----|--------------------|
|  1 |                  2 |
|  2 |                  1 |
|  3 |                  2 |
```

---

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d89a4e/1/0

```
SELECT d.`id`, COUNT(db.`doc_id`)
FROM `docs` d

LEFT JOIN `docs_scod_b` db ON db.`doc_id` = d.`id`
LEFT JOIN `scod_b` b ON b.id = db.`scod_b_id`

WHERE b.`ver_b` IN ('BA', 'BB')

GROUP BY d.`id`;

| id | COUNT(db.`doc_id`) |
|----|--------------------|
|  1 |                  2 |
|  2 |                  1 |
|  3 |                  2 |
```

---

What I want to Do is to merge both Queries into a Single one That **will not** only use (3-Tables)**x2** only, So I've tried the following Query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d2954/2/0

```
SELECT d.`id`, COUNT(da.`doc_id`), COUNT(db.`doc_id`)
FROM `docs` d

LEFT JOIN `docs_scod_a` da ON da.`doc_id` = d.`id`
LEFT JOIN `scod_a` a ON a.id = da.`scod_a_id`

LEFT JOIN `docs_scod_b` db ON db.`doc_id` = d.`id`
LEFT JOIN `scod_b` b ON b.`id` = db.`scod_b_id`

WHERE a.ver_a IN ('AC', 'AB') AND b.ver_b IN ('BA', 'BB')

GROUP BY d.`id`;
```

---

What I expected to get from this Query was the following results:

```
| id | COUNT(da.`doc_id`) | COUNT(db.`doc_id`) |
|----|--------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |                  2 |                  2 |
|  2 |                  1 |                  1 |
|  3 |                  2 |                  2 |
```

But Instead of That I got

```
| id | COUNT(da.`doc_id`) | COUNT(db.`doc_id`) |
|----|--------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |                  4 |                  4 |
|  3 |                  2 |                  2 |
```

---

Is the Problm on the `COUNT` only or Am I using the wrong method to `SELECT` data from **3-Tables Relation**?

So in Berif: How can I select data from 3-Tables Relation, And merge them together, Then `COUNT` result of each **relation**,

In the end I'll `SUM` the count for each row into one, So the final result expection overall after all of this is supposed to be

```
| id | SUM(COUNT(da.`doc_id`) + COUNT(db.`doc_id`))|
|----|---------------------------------------------|
|  1 |                                           4 |
|  2 |                                           2 |
|  3 |                                           4 |
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74321/discussion-on-question-by-matheo-select-in-2-merged-3-tables-relation-with-in).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're multiplying the joins, and you get what you ask for.  Scalar selects may be what you want:

```
select X.id, X.sda + X.sdb sumsummerdesum from (
SELECT d.`id`  id,
 (select COUNT(da.`doc_id`)
  from `docs_scod_a` da,  `scod_a` a
  where da.`doc_id` = d.`id`
    and a.id = da.`doc_id`
    and a.ver_a in ( 'AA', 'AC')
 ) sda,
 (select COUNT(db.`doc_id`)
   from `docs_scod_b` db, `scod_b` b
   where db.`doc_id` = d.`id`
     and b.`id` = db.`doc_id`
     and b.ver_b in ('BA','BB')
 ) sdb
FROM `docs` d
) X
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fee4c6/39

```
id  sumsummerdesum
1   6
2   1
3   2
4   0
```

Comment: I'm absolutly sorry about my blindness in the part of `LEFT JOIN scod_x x ON x.id = dx.doc_id`, Didn't notice untill now that I used the wrong column and fixed it to `LEFT JOIN scod_x x ON x.id = dx.scod_x_id`, Absolutly sorry about dragging you with my blindness and stupidity at this point.

Comment: Should've seen it myself. Just make the same replacements in my query.

Answer (score 1):

Extra conditions added to the scalar select - trying to answer the "IN()" problem:

```
SELECT d.`id`,
 (select COUNT(da.`doc_id`)
  from `docs_scod_a` da,  `scod_a` a
  where da.`doc_id` = d.`id`
    and a.id = da.`doc_id`
    and a.ver_a = 'AA'
 ) sda,
 (select COUNT(db.`doc_id`)
   from `docs_scod_b` db, `scod_b` b
   where db.`doc_id` = d.`id`
     and b.`id` = db.`doc_id`
     and b.ver_b = 'BB'
 ) sdb
FROM `docs`
```

Resulting in:

```
id  sda     sdb
1   3       0
2   0       1
3   0       0
4   0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL 8 on, you can use CTE - you may need to handle the nulls:

```
with sda (aI,aC) as (select da.`doc_id` I, COUNT(da.`doc_id`) C
  from `docs_scod_a` da,  `scod_a` a
  where a.id = da.`doc_id`
  group by da.`doc_id`
 ),
 sdb (bI,bC ) as (select db.`doc_id` I, COUNT(db.`doc_id`) C
   from `docs_scod_b` db, `scod_b` b
   where  b.`id` = db.`doc_id`
   group by db.`doc_id`
 )
SELECT d.`id`, sda.aC, sdb.bC
  FROM `docs` d
  left outer join sda on d.`id` = sda.aI
  left outer join sdb on d.`id` = sdb.bI
```

giving

```
id  aC      bC
1   3       3
2   3       1
3   2       3
4   null    1
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fBNDvSYXgFRfWU4778WvJB/0